# Make inline SVG fit its contents

Tags: css, svg, inline-svg

When you need to make a div as small as possible while still big enough for its children, you can just set it to `display: inline-block` or `position: absolute`.

That doesn't work with `<svg>`. In this example:

```
<svg style="display: inline-block">
  <path d="whatever" />
</svg>
```

If the `path` only takes up 20x20, the `svg` element will still take 300x150 (or whatever the browser default is).

How can you achieve the same result?

Comment: Can you not just set the width to 100% on the svg style?

Comment: set width and height so the UA has something to work with other than its default. Alternatively you could set a viewBox which the UA can also use to infer a height and width.

Comment: @Jonathan If I set it to 100% it'll be 100% of its parent. I want it to fit its contents only

Comment: @RobertLongson I want to know if it's possible for the UA to calculate the width and height automatically based on its contents, without using a viewBox. Similar to `display: inline-block` for divs.